# Replace text and empty lines in txt file

Tags: python-3.x

Want to replace `|` with `;` and remove empty lines in a `.txt` file and save as a `.csv` file.

My code so far - the replacement works but it does not remove empty lines. And it save same line twice in the `.csv`:

```
f1 = open("txtfile.txt", 'r+')
f2 = open("csvfile.csv", 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('|', ';'))
    if line.strip():
        f2.write(line)
        print(line)
    
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `f2.write(line.replace('|', ';'))` converts line by replacing the `|` to `;` and writes to csv file without checkng emptiness. So you are getting empty lines in csv file. Again in the `if` condition, `f2.write(line)` writes the original line once more. That is why you are getting same line (well almost) twice.

Instead of writing the modified line to file, save the it to `line` like -

```
for line in f1:
    line = line.replace('|', ';')
    if line.strip():
        f2.write(line)
```

Here we are first modifying the `line` to change `|` to `;` and overwrite `line` with the modified content. Then it checks for emptiness and writes in the csv file. So, the line is printed once and empty lines are skipped.

```
for line in f1:
    if line.strip(): # Check emptiness first
        f2.write(line.replace('|', ';')) # then directly write modified line
```